# An incomplete yet decidable theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am working on the following exercise from Boolos' *Computability and Logic*:

> **Problem.** Suppose an axiomatizable theory $T$ has only infinite models.  Suppose $T$ is not complete, [yet has] two isomorphism types of denumerable models.  Show that $T$ is decidable.

We are told to use the following two results:

> **Prop. 1** If an axiomatizable theory $T$ is complete, then $T$ is decidable.
>
> **Prop. 2** If $\Gamma$ is a denumerably categorical set of sentences having no finite models, then $\Gamma$ is complete.

Here is how I would proceed.  Take a sentence $A$ which for which neither $A$ nor $\neg A$ is a theorem of $T$.  Then take $\Gamma = T\cup\{A\}$.  If we can show that $\Gamma$ is a denumerably categorical set, then by Props. 1 and 2 we are finished.

Any hints, though, on how to show that $T\cup\{A\}$ is a denumerably categorical set?  In other words, why is it the case that adding $A$ to $T$ causes the isomorphism type to drop from two to one?

Comment: Here's one example. Consider the language $\{R\}$ and the axioms stating "if $R$ is anti-symmetric, then $R$ is a dense linear order without endpoints" and "if $R$ is not anti-symmetric, then $R$ is the trivial equivalence relation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If neither $A$ nor $\neg A$ is a theorem of $T$, then both $T\cup\{\neg A\}$ and $T\cup\{A\}$ must be satisfiable - by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, that means that there are denumerable models.

Now when we add (say) $A$ to $T$, we "lose" a(n isomorphism type of a) denumerable model - namely, the model of $T\cup\{\neg A\}$. Since $T$ only had two denumerable models to begin with, how many does that leave?

Comment: But how do we know that adding a sentence $A$ to a theory $T$ does not increase (rather than decrease) the number of unique denumerable models?

Comment: @Doubt You can't gain models by adding sentences. Adding sentences makes it *harder*, not *easier*, to satisfy the whole theory: if $\Theta\subseteq\Gamma$ then the class of models of $\Gamma$ is a subclass of the class of models of $\Theta$. Contrapositively, you can't *lose* models by *removing* sentences: if $\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma$ and $\Theta\subseteq\Gamma$ then $\mathcal{M}\models\Theta$.

Comment: Thanks Noah.  But suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are non-isomorphic models for $T$.  Isn't it possible that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are *both* models of $T\cup\{A\}$, but *neither* is a model of $T\cup\{\neg A\}$?

Comment: @Doubt **No, that's not possible** if $T$ has only two countable models and $T\cup\{\neg A\}$ is consistent: since $T\cup\{\neg A\}$ is consistent, it has a countable model, which can't be isomorphic to either $M_1$ or $M_2$ in the situation you describe (you can't be isomorphic to something satisfying $A$ while satisfying $\neg A$ yourself). But then we get too many isomorphism types of countable models.